# JSReport request error

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsreport

I am trying to access the jsreport api to render a report template and I am getting the following error:

```
{
    body: "{"body":"\"{\\\"template\\\":{\\\"shortid\\\":\\\"B1z8vSImQ\\\"}}\"","status":400,"statusCode":400}",
    code: 500,
    headers: {
        connection: "close",
        content-length: "99",
        content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        date: "Mon, 16 Jul 2018 14:22:54 GMT",
        etag: "W/"63-y7OYa6jmSZpY//j8j8VDr2CKCZg"",
        server: "nginx/1.15.0",
        x-powered-by: "Express"
    }
}
```

Here is how I am calling the api:

```
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    //strictSSL: false,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + hash,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        template: { shortid: 'B1z8vSImQ' }
    }),
    // auth: {
    //    username,
    //    password
    // }
}

requestify.request('https://gabrielsch.jsreportonline.net/api/report', options)
    .then(response => {

    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Does anyone know what might be happening? I can't find any resource on this anywhere. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing duplicated `JSON.stringify`. Remove it like this:

```
const options = {
    method: 'POST',  
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + hash,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: {
        template: { shortid: 'B1z8vSImQ' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved the problem. On a side note, are you familiar with the jsreport api?